# Include Lambda's Python dependencies in uploaded zipfile or download from S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

What results in faster lambda function start-up time: including the project's Python dependencies within the uploaded zipfile (via `pip install ... -t .`), or downloading said dependencies from an S3 bucket (through downloading those dependencies before the lambda handler function invokes the lambda function's core logic)?

I see the benefit in storing the dependencies within an S3 bucket in an attempt to minimize the size of the uploaded zipfile, as this practice of **minimizing your deployment package size to its runtime necessities** is listed as a [best practice for working with AWS Lambda functions.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html)

However, I could also see the drawback of locating dependencies externally as these extra network delays might require more time to complete than simply bundling the dependencies together.

Comment: Given my personal experience with AWS products, they really try to make things well performant and they employ pretty good ops team to improve their infrastructure. What you are asking is basically: "can I do a better job than the AWS ops team at networking data within their own data center?". If you feel likely that they would do a worse job than you, go ahead and run both to benchmark and see the results. Publish later on a blog post or something. I might be wrong, but I think this is not a topic that qualifies for SO...

Comment: I suppose that something simple like this question would likely have been taken into account when designing both services, so I suppose it might not be something to worry about. However, thank you for the blog post idea! I will benchmark both and write about the results.